# Why Handle and not any type for network in Haskell?

Tags: networking, haskell, types

The type of sent and received data over network is String, or Bytestring. We can't send any other types, like `Int`, or `[Bool]` for example, because everything passed through a `Handle`.
I know we can parse it, even using `read`, but I think it's not beautiful, nor reliable, and effective as well.

Why was this choice made? Is it because it's technically "impossible" otherwise, or because `Network` is just a binding to a C library, because of delays, or because of something else?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The data going over the network is just a stream of bytes. You can assign meaning to that stream of bytes at either endpoint, but on the network it has no meaning. As far as I know, this is true of every language, some just choose to abstract that away in their standard library.

You can encode/decode the data you're sending with packages like [binary](http://code.haskell.org/binary/) or [cereal](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/cereal) (using the `encode` and `decode` functions). Both come with instances of their serialization classes (`Binary` and `Serialize`, respectively) for many of the standard types like `Int`, `Double`, `Bool`, and `[]`.

Comment: Isn't every Haskell data also a stream of bytes at the lowest level? The libraries you name seems pretty cool! I think they can fix this issue.

Comment: @L01man: Good point. The designers of the network library probably chose not to abstract anything in order to preserve interoperability. For example, suppose you want to communicate between a Python program and a Haskell program. Python encodes `int`s differently than Haskell encodes `Integer`s, so it's necessary to drop down a level of abstraction to make the communication possible.

Comment: The problem is, you need to decide how to represent your datatypes as a bytestream -- there is no single standard or obvious way to do it.  This conversion of native dataypes into a bytestring is called serialization: your data representation convention is determined by the serialization package you use.

Comment: Okay, so it's rather a choice.